# Install MobSF in GCP, can't access port 8000

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to install MobSF to test every my mobile apps that I develop before.
Since I don't have many environment in my local PC, so I create a compute engine in GCP.
All installation is running well and completed.

[image]

My problem is, I can't access MobSF via external/public IP from GCP.
[image]

when I ping to my external IP, it's no problem.
I think this problem caused by firewall configuration that I must open port 8000.
But I don't know how to create correct firewall setting.
I was try to create before, but still failed.

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely that you might have not checked the ‘Allow HTTP traffic’ box of Firewall while creating the Virtual machine. If so, please follow the below mentioned steps and then try accessing your application from the web browser.

1. Click on the VM name
2. In the VM instance details page, click on EDIT button
3. Select the ‘Allow HTTP traffic’ under firewalls option and save.

Comment: I allow both http and https traffic

Comment: Ok. I understand from the chat(https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235631/discussion-between-caiot-and-potitit) that your issue is resolved and now you could connect to the Mobsf application thru RDP.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to open port 8000 to the world, you can create a firewall rule as below (considering you are using the default vpc):

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create "allow8000" --allow=tcp:8000
    --source-ranges="0.0.0.0/0" --description="Allow 8000 external"
```

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create

Edit: if you want to do a more granular firewall control to specify only one compute engine (the one you mentioned) you need either use network tags or allow only the private IP of that instance.

Also, I just noticed that you've started the app with the loopback address. Have you tried to start it up to listen to all interfaces "0.0.0.0"?

Comment: hi, 
Did you mean I must create firewall rules via cloud shell ? or via SSH to my compute engine ?
and 1 more question sir, is that command will make any impact to my another compute engine ?
Thanks

Comment: Just edited my answer with a few other points

Comment: I've tried set to listen all interfaces 0.0.0.0/0 , but still doesn't work.
I also check in my compute engine, it's really listen to 8000.

Comment: I meant to say, you must open the port/create a firewall rule then listen to all interfaces within your app.

Comment: yes,
I've already create firewall rules and set my app to listen all interfase.
`tcp        0      0 localhost:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

this is my firewall rules :
`Type : Ingress
Targets : Apply to all 
Filter : IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
Protocol / ports : tcp:8000 udp:8080
action : Allow
priority : 1000
network : default
logs : Off`

It still not work. Any correction sir ?

Comment: Is this compute instance attached to the default VPC?

Comment: yes, It's default VPC.
maybe I must create my own VPC ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235631/discussion-between-caiot-and-potitit).